# Help regarding a shell script

Tags: shell, service, daemon

I was creating a init.d service, and was reading a few scripts for reference. I found this one in a skeleton:

What does this snippet do? I get that this is a switch:case. I am asking about the case within the case.

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        echo test
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
```

PS: Excuse the title, I couldn't think of a better name

Thanks.

Comment: What this snippet does is *syntax error*, since it is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the actual script might have had something more substantial than 'echo test'. $? is the exit code returned by the echo command in this script. The inner case statement prints the log message that is appropriate for the termination code. 0|1 most likely is success. 2 is probably an error.

Comment: I just have this line: `cd /usr/share/jetty; /usr/bin/java -jar start.jar`

Comment: In that case, it will check the exit status of the java process.

Answer (score 0):

$? holds the exit code of the last executed command.
If 0 - there were no errors.